# Android Development - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: !=

Tags: java, android, ssl, wifi

I'm having some issues with my Application, I believe it to be an issue where clients are connecting through a public wifi connection, resolving the current DNS and the application noticing it as a 'middle man' thus raise error in code and causing the bug report
"

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: !="
```

I have implemented URL and IP checking in seperate functions below, but I'd love to inquire into any 'best practice' standards there would be for dealing with open WIFI(Such as OpenBT or Mcdonalds wifi) that require a login/pay purchase but register as real wifi connections.

Below is an example of a JSON request code which was originally flagging the error. And below that is a check URL function which checks a URL, and the correct IP to see if they can resolve against each other.

Thanks for any time spent helping me with this query!

```
    protected static jsonHandler jhJSONRequest(String strType, Cursor c, Context myContext) throws Exception {
    jsonHandler myReturnValues = jhTableToJSON(strType, c, myContext);

    String strPath = "https://www.******.co.uk/****/*****/******/json_collector.ashx?";
    strPath += "dttablet=" + ES_Functions.lngGetCurrentDateTime(myContext);
    strPath += "&engid=" + intEngineerID(myContext);
    strPath += "&tabletid=" + ES_Functions.strUniqueID(myContext);
    strPath += "&key=" + strJSONKey;
    strPath += "&" + strType.toLowerCase() + "=1";

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(strPath);

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(myReturnValues.strJSON);

    httpost.setEntity(se);
    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new Exception("JSON Response Failed");
    } else {
        return myReturnValues;
    }
}


protected static boolean checkURL(String strUrl, String strIP)
{
    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
    boolean portReached = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(strIP);
        if(address.equals(addr))
        {
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, 80);
            // Create an unbound socket
            Socket sock = new Socket();

            // This method will block no more than timeoutMs.
            // If the timeout occurs, SocketTimeoutException is thrown.
            int timeoutMs = 2000;   // 2 seconds
            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
            portReached = true;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.w(TAG, "--- NOTE - COULD NOT RESOLVE PORT ON INET SOCKET ---");

    }

    return portReached;

}
```

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` on Android has some notes on this: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html